# Is there a class of arguments for God that does not rely on knowledge of His work -- the world?

Tags: theology

I was just having a discussion in [comments](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/67648/bayes-and-unknown-probabilites-is-this-reasoning-from-the-failure-of-explanatio) (I won't recreate its details) that has convinced me that we can't know God through his work, through the world He is said to have created. Is there a class of argument (or in deed religion, if that's not off-topic) that does not exclude?

I'd guess it might not exclude the ontological argument, because it is a priori, and God may not be responsible for logic. But that it does exclude e.g. the cosmological argument, and argument from miracles.

Comment: That is too strong. The undermining of traditional arguments is based on finding natural explanations for what God used to be the best explanation of (purpose in nature, backstop of causal chains, commonality of world religions, etc.). There is no guarantee that conspicuous enough miracle, or some other phenomenon, would have such a natural explanation available.

Comment: Arguments like Aristotle's Prime Mover or Berkeley's Platonist overmind do not really work by using any given property of the world as leverage (taking it that existence is not a property).  They just presuppose God as a precondition of any world at all.  So it depends on what 'through' means in the foregoing argument.

Comment: good point, thanks @jobermark

Comment: In the East, the Advaita Vedanta and Mahayana Buddhism say this. His 'work' as you refer to it, the sensual universe, is an illusion. All is God. To see His work as separate from Him, is to accept a priori a dualistic extra-cosmic God as the only acceptable view of the Godhead. From a Western philosophic view, Plotinius' 'Six Enneads' presents these ideas.